# Moving data from one table to another in Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, data-transfer

I am moving around 10 million data from one table to another in SQL Server 2005. The Purpose of Data transfer is to Offline the old data.

After some time it throws an `error Description: "The LOG FILE FOR DATABASE 'tempdb' IS FULL."`.

My `tempdb` and `templog` is placed in a drive (other than C drive) which has around 200 GB free. Also my `tempdb` size in database is set to `25 GB`.

As per my understanding I will have to increase the size of `tempdb` from `25 GB` to `50 GB` and set the log file Auto growth portion to "`unrestricted file growth (MB)`".

Please let me know other factors and I cannot experiment much as I am working on Production database so can you please let me know if they changes will have some other impact.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think you can set the database's recovery mode to `simple`, which will greatly reduce logging.

Comment: Thanks , I will trying doing that...

Comment: @rudym Thanks for editing the question for proper understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the solution. Seems you are just moving part of data to make your queries faster.

I am agree with your solution

As per my understanding I will have to increase the size of tempdb from 25 GB to 50 GB and set the log file Auto growth portion to "unrestricted file growth (MB)".

Go ahead

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're trying to move all of the data in a single batch; can you break it up into smaller batches, and commit fewer rows as you insert?  Also, as noted in the comments, you may be able to set your destination database to SIMPLE or BULK-INSERT mode.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using Log file at all? Copy your data (Data and Logfile) then set the mode on SIMPLE and run the transfer again.